# Win32api's keybd_event() function problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, input, keyboard, pywin32

I'm having some issues creating inputs with the win32api. I'm creating a voice recognition script that needs to work just like a keyboard in all contexts (including fullscreen games and such). I've tried a few other solutions besides win32api's keybd_event() function but most don't even register in fullscreen applications. I'm using Civilization IV as the test program. Win32api's keybd_event() function does work in-game, but I'm getting some weird results. I've tried a few different things:

```
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_UP, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0)
win32api.Sleep(50)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_UP, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Does not work regardless of whether the second or third line is in there. It correctly registers as an up arrow press in applications like notepad. In Civilization, it correctly registers as an up arrow press (as opposed to the next solution below), ***but the key is never released*** and it tries to go up forever, seemingly ignoring the third line.

```
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_UP, 0, 0, 0)
win32api.Sleep(50)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_UP, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

Has a completely different problem. In Civilization that code tries to press ***not the up arrow key, but the numpad up (8) key*** regardless of whether numlock is on or off.

It's weird because the two inputs do different things in game: The first block of code is clearly pressing the arrow up key (but not letting go of it) and the second block of code is clearly pressing the numpad up (8) key, even though the first argument (which key to press) is the same.

What is wrong with the first block of code? What is wrong with the second block of code? What is a good solution? Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unsure exactly why this works, but experimenting randomly I have found a solution using the bitwise OR. The code that I partially copied is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

My solution:

```
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_UP, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0) #press
win32api.Sleep(50)
win32api.keybd_event(win32con.VK_UP, 0, win32con.KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | win32con.KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0) #release
```

I'll mark this as the accepted answer for now since it works and there are no other answers, (and I still can't find any good documentation) but if anyone has a good explanation of exactly what is going on here then that would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: This does not work for me in League of Legends. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pepijn I never figured out why the above worked, or why the two sections of code in the original question didn't work/why they caused such odd behavior.  Did you try those two?  Maybe try some combination of the three sections of code (original two, and my working one)?  Sorry I can't be more help.

Answer (score 0):

i don't sure what the problem with civilization but i supose the problem is the Virtual Input that winapi uses, because i have a similar problem but in my problem the program don't recognizes the input

So u can install python libs that uses the direct input because modern games like GTA-V uses the system based in DirectX input i think

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).