# Issue with keybd_event event

Tags: .net, powershell, winapi

```
$Signature = @"
[DllImport("user32.dll")]public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);
"@
$keybd_event = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Signature -Name "Win32keybd_event" -Namespace Win32Functions -PassThru


$VK_LSHIFT = 0xA0
$KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001
$KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002

$keybd_event::keybd_event($VK_LSHIFT, 0, $KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0)
sleep 2
$keybd_event::keybd_event($VK_LSHIFT, 0, $KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
```

I expect: press shift, wait 2 sec, release shift button.

But after code is finished, shift is still in "down" state(try to click somewhere on the text in console or ISE). (The cure is shift+left mouse click)

Why this happens, how to fix it and do it properly?

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event)? Also note that the final argument is pointer-sized.

Comment: @IInspectable , dwFlags in first call should be 0, correct?

Comment: You need to specify the `EXTENDEDKEY` flag when releasing as well. Change `$keybd_event::keybd_event($VK_LSHIFT, 0, $KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)` to `$keybd_event::keybd_event($VK_LSHIFT, 0, ($KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY -bor $KEYEVENTF_KEYUP), 0)`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen , `$keybd_event::keybd_event($VK_LSHIFT, 0, $KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0) ; sleep 2 ; $keybd_event::keybd_event($VK_LSHIFT, 0, ($KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY -bor $KEYEVENTF_KEYUP), 0)` - correct?

Comment: @Danny LGTM - has the desired effect on my machine as well :)

Comment: The docs say "Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Win32api's keybd\_event() function problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31713835/win32apis-keybd-event-function-problems)

Comment: @cha `SendInput` allows you to inject *a sequence of events* atomically into the input buffer. The OP expressly does not want to inject a sequence of events. They want to inject two discrete events, at two different points in time. The potential issue with `keybd_event` that `SendInput` solves is not an issue here. Using `SendInput` doesn't provide any benefit here.